# F# - Convert Task<unit> to plain Task

Tags: .net, f#, task-parallel-library

I'm using Giraffe to create native .NET Tasks with Async workflows since I need interoperability with the Discord.NET library.  I've got an event that takes a `Task`, but the event handler that I'm writing returns a `Task<unit>` and for some reason the type checker isn't smart enough to realize that it's the same thing.  Is there a way to convert the `Task<unit>` to a straight up `Task`?

Here's my code:

```
let messageReceived (msg : SocketMessage) =
    task {
        let author = msg.Author.Username
        let text = msg.Content
        match msg.Author.Username with
            | "Monika" -> ()
            | usr ->
                if text.ToLower().StartsWith "<@407367655830585344> say" then
                    text.Substring 26 |> msg.Channel.SendMessageAsync |> ignore
                else if text.ToLower().StartsWith "<@407367655830585344>" then
                    let response = (Lines.VoiceLines |> Extras.randomElement).Replace("[player]", author)
                    msg.Channel.SendMessageAsync response |> ignore
                else if text.ToLower().StartsWith "delete" then
                    text.Substring 7 + ".chr deleted" |> msg.Channel.SendMessageAsync |> ignore
                else if Extras.onein 10 then
                    let response = (Lines.VoiceLines |> Extras.randomElement).Replace("[player]", author)
                    msg.Channel.SendMessageAsync response |> ignore
    }

_client.add_MessageReceived (fun m -> messageReceived m)
```

The last line generates an error, saying that the `MessageReceived` event needs a function with the signature `SocketMessage -> Task`:

> error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type 'Task' but here has type 'Task<unit>'

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`Task` is the base class of `Task<T>`, so you should be able to upcast `Task<unit>` to `Task` with `:>` operator. Try something like this:

```
(fun m -> messageReceived m :> Task)
```

I think this minimal example reproduces the issue:

```
// int -> Task<unit>
let sleepTaskT (m : int) = Async.Sleep m |> Async.StartAsTask
// (int -> Task) -> Task
let foo (f : int -> Task) = f 1000
// "This expression was expected to have type 'Task' but here has type 'Task<unit>'"
foo (fun m -> sleepTaskT m)
// this works by explicitly upcasting sleepTaskT's Task<unit> to Task
foo (fun m -> sleepTaskT m :> Task)
```

Comment: You saved me a few hours. Thanks

Comment: I'm trying to go the other way, is there a more elegant way than `let asUnit (t: Task) = task { do! t; return () }`?